# How to draw text in multiple line in multiple pages using static layout for PDF Creation

Tags: android, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, staticlayout

I am using below code to draw text and write in PDF, but it is not able to draw in multiple pages? What would be the best approach for this problem.

```
 PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new
                PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageheight, 3).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();


            TextPaint paint=new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
            paint.setTextSize((int) (7 * 2));
            paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

            int textWidth = canvas.getWidth() - (int) (16 * 2);

            StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(
                    edittextContent.getText().toString(), paint, pageWidth-50, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

            int textHeight = textLayout.getHeight();

            float x = ((pageWidth-15) - textWidth)/2;
            float y = ((pageheight-15) - textHeight)/2;

            // draw text to the Canvas center
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(15, 10);
            textLayout.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();

        document.finishPage(page);
        document.writeTo(fOut);
        document.close();
```

Comment: This is exactly the same problem which I faced and didn't find any good answers.
I solved it by using StaticLayout and limiting the number of characters in a particular page, then divide the long string into that many pages accordingly, loop through it according to the number of pages and print. **Check my answer where I have explained with sample code how to handle it.** https://stackoverflow.com/a/71394812/12552434

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using native android `android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument`. It really looks like it only provides the low-level functionality of placing the text lines at specific coordinates on a specific page. If you want to stick to this API, you would probably need to call `startPage()` and `finishPage()` for every page that you want to create in your document and prepare split content for every page. Something like this:

```
// start 1st page
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
// draw something on the page
// finish 1st page
document.finishPage(page);

// start 2nd page
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
// draw something on the page
// finish 2nd page
document.finishPage(page);

...
```

If you want more high-level functionality which would span multiple pages if content doesn't fit, you would need to use some other tools.

E.g. you can try `iText7` library:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document document = new Document(pdf, new PageSize(pageWidth, pageheight));
// set here any amount of text, it will span across multiple pages if needed
String text = ...;
document.add(new Paragraph(line));
document.close();
```

See https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-adding-content-to-a-canvas-or-a-document for more examples.

Comment: Suppose If I have a very long string then how can your code help in auto multiline and multipage?..Even if I use StaticLayout  to solve the multiline problem the multipage problem stays